# vim command to run java

Tags: unix, vim, java

I'm trying to add a line to my .vimrc to run java.

If I type, `:! basename % .java | xargs java`

then all is good, but I cant get this into the vimrc without E492 Not an editor command.

I'd initially tried, `nmap <leader> J :! basename % .java | xargs java` and then tried to make a :Java command, but get the error both times. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it

```
command Java execute "! basename % .java | xargs java"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use backticks for executing the command:

```
map <F11> :!javac %; java `basename % .java`<CR>
```